# Error distribution for Huber Regression

Tags: regression, normal-distribution, linear, mae

For linear regression there's an assumption that error terms come from normal distribution. so that $Y = aX + b + \epsilon$, where $\epsilon$ has normal distribution with mean zero and certain variance.

Is there an analogous assumption for [Huber loss](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huber_loss) (or MAE which should be easier)? So that for a variable described by relation 
$Y = aX + b + \epsilon$ with $\epsilon$ from this distribution huber regression (or theoretically minimization of MAE) gives a and b parameters?